# Importing and Modifying Data in MySQL Workbench 6.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to MySQL and have not been coding for quite a few years. I am building a database in MySQL Workbench 6.0 and need to import multiple NEM12 text files from data logs. The text files have a Record Indicator (RI) as the first 3 characters (eg 200, 300, 900).

I need to get the second entry from the 200 RI lines (NMI)and add it to the following 300 lines as there is no reference to the NMI but this is the info I am interested. Note there is normally one 200 line for several hundred 300 lines. To further complicate this there will be another 200 line with a different NMI and 300 lines following that are for the new NMI.

**NMI Data Record 200**

```
RecordIndicator,NMI,NMIConfiguration,RegisterID,NMISuffix,MDMDataStreamIdentifier,
MeterSerialNumber,UOM,IntervalLength,NextScheduledReadDate
```

**Example**

```
200,VABD000163,E1Q1,1,E1,N1,METSER123,kWh,30,20040120
```

**NMI Data Record 300**

```
RecordIndicator,IntervalDate,IntervalValue1 . . . IntervalValueN,
QualityMethod,ReasonCode,ReasonDescription,UpdateDateTime,MSATSLoadDateTime
```

**Example**

```
300,20030501,50.1, . . . ,21.5,V,,,20030101153445,20030102023012
```

Some lines below are from the logfile - note that it doesn't have a line gap in the file between the lines

```
100,NEM12,201307101326,WBAYM,QEEE000514,

200,QEEE000514,E1Q1,,E1,N1,90401242,kWh,30,

300,20120701,67.46,80.42,85.38,85.22,82.3,79.23,71.23,81.41,93.82,100.93,125.89,113.79,102.37,117.25,125.7,140.16,134.14,127.62,123.3,144.13,144.48,157.73,141.28,143.74,135.71,148.48,151.81,160.32,148.67,145.41,135.62,148.35,128.7,142.37,136.1,141.31,98.21,102.14,80.86,82.69,74.3,75.84,69.15,75.01,67.78,72.96,66.75,71.1,A,,,20120702013914,

300,20120702,61.63,74.69,80.45,78.46,77.31,74.91,65.57,77.63,97.82,126.78,119.84,131.58,130.08,138.75,111.74,118.94,121.66,128.45,121.47,142.46,139.1,153.82,121.09,128.77,145.6,159.1,147.07,133.82,126.69,135.9,141.28,151.01,127.23,120.19,117.44,133.18,110.43,121.57,116.9,119.17,112.03,107.49,94.05,92.9,81.63,85.76,81.09,85.47,A,,,20120703013936,

300,20120703,71.46,71.33,78.94,76.83,77.57,72.86,65.92,78.85,97.73,124.77,118.69,130.14,127.46,136.35,107.74,116.13,115.46,127.55,120.74,133.79,138.98,147.84,123.17,123.33,117.98,133.66,122.69,137.28,129.73,120.45,139.81,150.37,128.32,120.74,112.67,115.46,114.24,127.42,113.25,122.43,108.8,107.71,92.8,90.46,79.84,83.74,81.12,83.2,A,,,20120704013954,
300,20120704,73.95,82.62,88.19,87.81,87.78,83.04,75.26,85.34,94.98,119.07,113.86,122.24,123.84,131.3,107.9,112.48,120.13,117.7,115.42,119.42,125.47,137.6,130.11,113.95,119.1,144.8,135.87,123.2,109.25,116.77,113.76,133.95,126.24,119.3,105.86,107.39,107.52,111.81,109.22,111.36,100.19,98.88,86.27,80.8,72.16,75.33,70.56,74.02,A,,,20120705013928,

300,20120705,60.7,61.47,70.43,66.56,67.14,63.9,56,67.26,88.8,113.66,106.75,118.78,118.08,124.8,101.15,105.82,112.86,118.27,121.22,135.3,130.08,122.27,111.62,120.26,105.12,132.13,139.52,134.5,116.32,124.03,125.31,137.98,111.52,111.97,104.38,117.25,106.78,122.62,106.46,106.82,100.38,102.72,86.46,77.31,71.01,72.26,69.28,71.71,A,,,20120706013931,
300,20120706,57.22,58.66,66.5,63.39,66.43,64.64,55.01,64.83,89.15,103.84,101.86,105.18,108.22,125.06,114.21,103.65,115.87,120.32,119.33,133.76,134.4,142.05,119.23,126.94,122.78,148.06,141.86,124.16,114.27,116,109.6,134.82,127.52,127.71,111.36,119.9,114.62,125.09,109.89,122.08,113.02,106.3,87.26,80.38,72.29,78.34,73.98,77.09,A,,,20120707013935,

300,20120707,64.61,66.21,72.22,70.85,75.14,72.93,62.75,71.46,79.81,96.54,108.38,100.93,112.45,125.18,117.44,103.36,113.86,128.35,122.59,130.08,122.82,119.52,123.74,141.7,132.67,133.66,116.61,130.85,125.31,133.44,112.42,124.03,115.81,120.9,89.22,89.79,77.06,90.59,81.98,86.88,80.99,82.98,76,76.7,62.37,66.82,63.1,65.98,A,,,20120708013912,
300,20120708,57.15,69.15,73.18,75.1,73.22,70.43,63.68,72.9,84.83,104.99,107.36,103.17,95.04,110.02,113.66,129.63,128.9,121.76,119.04,134.14,120.86,125.57,136.16,142.5,135.01,122.98,122.21,126.69,132.64,137.12,122.69,124.77,123.23,126.66,109.25,116.9,88.42,93.06,68.83,73.15,66.18,66.66,61.34,67.78,61.31,64.13,59.9,63.97,A,,,20120709013915,
300,20120709,52.96,65.57,72.48,70.46,69.95,68.16,59.68,72.99,90.91,122.43,115.04,124.58,124.51,134.27,113.12,112.03,117.41,120.26,123.04,144.51,139.52,151.52,115.74,127.46,125.44,133.92,127.04,135.01,134.98,136.67,109.28,132.1,129.73,136.48,120.35,120.93,112.19,128.19,115.71,124.77,117.15,111.71,97.44,91.46,81.92,82.69,80.51,82.91,A,,,20120710013929,
300,20120710,72.93,85.02,91.07,90.98,89.18,86.56,74.18,88.1,102.18,122.34,115.9,122.82,128.06,139.58,116.7,116.99,120.03,124.26,117.47,144.26,143.17,141.22,123.81,124.32,115.97,148.45,144.7,147.94,124.38,126.66,118.53,142.98,136.13,134.59,118.27,121.95,116,128.16,116.38,118.46,110.02,108.86,96.22,92.64,80.38,86.94,80.1,83.84,A,,,20120711013916,
300,20120711,64.16,70.94,77.22,75.94,76.8,71.39,62.82,76.22,98.24,119.87,117.09,127.33,123.3,135.07,105.76,115.94,117.66,124.74,124.1,141.09,136.93,141.98,119.17,126.78,119.04,135.78,140.7,144.19,127.07,120.61,117.6,129.89,133.22,140.48,122.62,128.67,114.08,121.82,115.87,125.86,111.2,108.58,94.37,91.97,80.58,84.06,80.38,80.86,A,,,20120712013916,
300,20120712,67.3,70.75,77.31,75.55,75.1,72.06,63.78,77.73,93.38,113.44,119.94,119.87,125.57,137.12,113.89,116.1,118.46,123.17,127.49,142.18,145.38,150.98,135.26,134.62,136.42,164.74,155.78,142.4,135.04,140.51,126.21,145.09,138.3,137.18,126.69,126.37,125.47,129.86,120.32,117.76,110.69,112.26,98.18,92.38,81.54,86.98,81.73,86.27,A,,,20120713013923,
300,20120713,65.02,73.06,77.02,75.71,75.39,72.38,64.86,75.49,97.82,113.6,117.18,116.38,117.25,137.31,127.78,121.15,127.39,123.55,118.27,134.66,143.65,145.34,128.9,140.32,142.5,147.65,134.05,155.01,129.82,123.33,114.88,126.59,118.02,122.66,115.62,116.51,105.79,118.14,107.9,113.86,104.38,108.1,93.41,92.96,72.96,75.3,69.76,72.86,A,,,20120714014000,
300,20120714,63.74,78.56,81.82,82.98,80.54,79.78,69.73,82.4,103.17,123.84,118.78,128.1,131.1,144.99,117.31,127.01,123.49,136.74,126.62,150.98,148.03,153.73,132.38,139.23,153.92,162.08,172.83,142.98,142.3,145.34,149.25,134.24,125.12,126.27,98.21,99.07,87.42,100.06,90.27,95.94,80.51,78.34,70.11,78.3,69.25,72.54,68.67,72.96,A,,,20120715014259,
300,20120715,63.52,77.18,82.46,81.95,80.61,77.63,69.66,83.42,96.32,104.58,110.18,122.08,106.5,134.53,135.55,133.44,107.65,124.35,124.35,130.75,136.67,147.01,142.72,126.37,124.74,154.5,139.55,128.54,121.31,129.38,118.37,128.51,114.69,118.5,118.91,112.42,82.98,89.98,76.32,76.35,71.58,74.21,66.88,73.79,66.66,68.77,68,69.7,A,,,20120716013951,
300,20120716,63.9,86.4,90.24,91.01,90.11,85.31,78.43,87.9,102.08,127.26,125.18,131.36,132.13,134.14,110.34,121.7,123.2,122.72,118.08,135.26,133.09,139.62,116.32,131.55,121.22,146.91,140.32,127.78,120.42,139.94,133.47,137.15,120,124.35,115.55,118.59,114.72,124.86,119.14,122.72,109.63,107.55,92.83,88.99,78.11,79.58,74.18,78.88,A,,,20120717013928,
300,20120717,63.62,66.21,73.02,70.11,70.88,66.98,59.2,72.06,96.8,136.67,128.48,129.7,131.36,139.97,112.26,123.04,130.5,135.42,142.85,163.33,147.07,140.45,131.23,149.31,144.32,164.16,159.36,141.18,136.03,142.18,149.66,166.11,142.37,133.95,131.78,133.22,125.15,130.3,127.74,128.38,125.28,120.96,98.11,93.31,87.33,91.55,80.9,94.14,A,,,20120718013923,
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not easy to understand. Please provide relevant sequence of lines in your file and desired output based on it.

Comment: And what is the desired (expected) output from the query?

Comment: Hi Peter, I would like a table that looks at a the 200 line, takes the NMI (QEEE000514) and the NMISuffix(E1) and makes a table with these as the first two columns and the data in the 300 rows as the rest.

Comment: Ok. Is the number of `IntervalValue` fields in `300` line always constant?

Comment: yes - the no of fields is the same. I am assuming I have to create a temp table that does some modification then load into a database with the right headers. Another 200 line may come further down the file which means that the NMI or the NMI Suffix might change